# I have a similar product manufactured in Europe since 2009. How do I oppose the granting of this patent application?

Tags: patentability, patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US20150118365](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150118365)

Comment: Would it be possible to include some public documentation about your product? Including the claims of this application next to your prior art is a great way to get started.

Answer (score 1):

By providing a third party observation to the USPTO. This is basically sending prior art and reasoning to why the patent application should not be granted to the examiner. They should carefully consider this, however you will not be part of the examination process, so for example they won't ask for clarification.

You can easily do this through the EPO website, just go to the patent application and look for the submit observation button.

Answer (score 0):

First check patent is granted or not by US patent office. You need to file post grant opposition for above patent if it gets grant in future.

Comment: It might help to include some details (even in the form of a link or two to the USPTO's site) on how to do this. Just high-level stuff: where would you go to check on the status, for instance?

Comment: One such site is: https://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions